# Do sites know my name when I'm signed in to Google?

Tags: google-account, privacy, website

When I visit a site like https://medium.com/, I see a popup asking me if I want to "sign in to medium.com with Google", along with my Google account's name and profile picture.

How does this work? Does this mean that sites are able to access my name and profile picture when I'm signed in to Google?

Comment: If you see your Google account name and profile picture before pressing the "Sign in with Google" button (which redirects you to a Google page) that means that you have been signed in on that page before just the login session seem to have timed-out and need to be renewed or somthing like this.

Comment: No, not as far as i know, signing in just uses the google credentials, no personal information is passed on.

Comment: See [Use your Google Account to sign in to other sites or apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/112802?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: You're describing this feature: https://superuser.com/q/1414410/122042

Answer (score 2):

When you sign in using Google on any site, Google sends back the following data to the site:

1. Your name (Display name)
2. Your email ID
3. Your profile picture (Actually it's a url to your profile picture)

If a site needs any data other than name, email and profile picture then the user is prompted to grant the permission for the site to access the requested resources.